# How do I recover lost mails from Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have created a new rule in Microsoft Outlook but surprisingly all the mails which where previously in that new created rule are all lost. How do I recover the lost mails?

Answer (score 1):

Your e-mails are probably not lost, just misplaced :)

First you should take another look at your newly created rule. Is it really doing what you intended?

Then you could check your filtering in your inbox. Too often I see users who have accidently pressed some button in Outlook which then filters out all read e-mails (for example). Check the line just above your e-mails.

Have you checked all folders? Press the plus-sign next to the Inbox and see if anything happens.

Last: Have you looked in deleted items?